# Roslyn Analyzers not working after converting to new csproj

Tags: c#, visual-studio, csproj, roslyn-code-analysis

We recently converted a `.NET 451` solution to the new `csproj` structure. In doing so our custom Rosyln analzyers (referenced as a nuget package from a private feed) seem to have stopped working, both in VS and when building manually. There are no build errors coming from that package. The new `csproj` is too large to post here but all the obvious analyzers stuff is in there including the package reference to the analyzers themselves and the correct `CodeAnalysis` properties:

```
<RunCodeAnalysis>true</RunCodeAnalysis>
<CodeAnalysisRuleSet>..\Standard.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
```

There is no GlobalSuppression file in the solution.

Separately for testing I have created a simple `net451` class library, converted to the new `csproj` and seen that the above works fine. But our project is massive - the `csproj` alone is ~3K lines. So something somewhere is nullifying or suppressing our rules. I have pored over the entire `csproj` file and there is nothing obviously wrong.

Has anyone had this issue in converting a `net framework` solution to the new `csproj` structure?

Comment: Have you tried installing Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers? Here is similar issue: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/133059/vs2017-code-analysis-not-working.html

Comment: The SDK-style projects definitely support analyzers. If you're still seeing this problem, please open a bug on https://github.com/dotnet/project-system.